# Viewing script logs shows "No logs found. Use Logger API to add logs to your project."

Tags: logging, google-apps-script

According to the training I created a spreadsheet in Google Docs LearnBasics, opened the Script Editor (under Tools menu) and followed the first videos and wrote the scripts. Every time, after writing and running a script, I went into "View Logs" and every time I could successfully view the log content as expected.

Then next day after the training I returned, wanting to start writing my own script, (a keyword-to-category lookup function to categorize my bank transactions for accounting and tax purposes).

But mysteriously when wanting to view the log it returned this message: 
"No logs found. Use Logger API to add logs to your project."

I have been researching to find how I could solve my issue, I even signed up for a one year trial of Google Cloud Platform, which I don't think I need.

I had found this question:
[How do I "Use Logger API to add logs to your project"? (Google Script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44846833/how-do-i-use-logger-api-to-add-logs-to-your-project-google-script)
but the answers did not help me. I do not see any Console Logger in the Script Editor menu, nor in GCP.

I also checked out this page:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger
and tried out the suggestions, but did not get to any result.

How can I ensure my logs aren't deleted?

Answer (score 4):

In short, this is because the Apps Script [`Logger`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger) is not meant for long-term logging - it is meant for short term (e.g. single-instance/invocation lifetime) debugging. Other Apps Script built-ins, such as Stackdriver Logging via [`console`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/console), offer a longer-term logging period.

If you want to actually store the logs indefinitely, you will need to serialize the content (e.g. write the logs to a spreadsheet or other file). An example of this for the `Logger` class:

```
function writeLogs() {
  const logText = Logger.getLogs();
  if (!logText)
    return;

  // Convert the log string to a directly-serializable 2D array:
  const logs = logText.split("\n").map(function (log) { return [log]; });
  if (!logs || !logs.length || !logs[0].length) {
    console.error({
      message: "Unexpected issue creating log array",
      full_log_text: logText,
      log_array: logs
    }); // Record issue in Stackdriver logs.
    return;
  }

  // Write the log to our logging sheet in the logging workbook.
  const wb = SpreadsheetApp.openById("some id");
  const sheet = wb.getSheetByName("some sheet name");
  if (sheet) {
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, logs.length, logs[0].length)
        .setValues(logs);
    Logger.clear();
  }
}
```

A good place to start is the [Logging Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging)

Related Q:
 - [Logger log cleared automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48176433/logger-log-cleared-automatically)

Comment: Thank you tehhowch,